# Is there a maximum directory depth std::ifstream can access? C++

Tags: c++, std, fstream, ifstream

I am working on a project in which I need to read/open an .stl from any arbitrary directory. This is what I have for opening a file:

```
int ReadStl( std::string fname, std::vector<ReadFacet>& mesh)
{
    std::ifstream ifs;
    ifs.open(fname, std::ios::binary);
... stl reading and processing...
    return 0;
}
```

As I understand it, I can pass the complete file path and name like so:
fname =  "C:/Users/Luke/folder1/example.stl"
This works for the most part, but fails once I go more than 6 folders deep...
Any ideas on why this happens or what is wrong with my solution?
I am still relatively new to C++ so any input/corrections are welcomed.

Comment: There may (depending on how you use and OS option) be a ~256 character limit on path length: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation?tabs=registry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation?tabs=registry)

Comment: `std::ifstream` has no idea about directories or depth or anything like that. You pass it a filename, it passes that filename to the OS.

Comment: There is a platform-specific limit as to how long a file path name can be. It appears you're running on a Windows platform, so you may [find this interesting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation?tabs=registry).

Comment: Just a note for SO (also, welcome!), is to never post a file path with your profile name in it, as that may be your actual. There is no official rule saying this, just a recommendation for me.

Comment: @drescherjm very useful resource, but is seems my troubles are not due to the length of the string, just the number of folders the file is buried in.

Comment: There should not be any limitation to the number of folders just the length of the path caused by having a deep hierarchy of folders.

Comment: Some of the WinAPI functions work better if the `W`ide versions are used. What about `std::ifstream ifs(std::filesystem::path(fname), std::ios::binary);` - does that make a difference? It could "trick it" into using the better native function. You may also try using `std::wstring fname;` and `std::filesystem::path(fname)` or go for a `std::wifstream`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo standard `std::wifstream` does not accept a `wchar_t`-based file path. The `w` refers to the stream's reading of `wchar_t` data from the file, vs `std::ifstream` reading `char` data instead. However, Microsoft has non-standard extensions to `std::ifstream` and `std::wifstream` to accept `wchar_t`-based file paths.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I didn't mean to suggest opening a `wifstream` with a `wstring` (the _"or go for a `std::wifstream`"_ part was meant as a last resort if going through a `path` with a `wstring` didn't help) - but nice to know that it's possible in MSVC.